# What is this top guide hole on my fishing rod?

Tags: fishing, fishing-rods

I was given a St. Croix Avid AS60MLF, and I have no idea why this top guide is on the opposite side.  The rest of the guides are on the same side as the lower one in the picture.  Only the top one is on the "top" side of the rod with the rest on the "bottom".  What is this for?

[image: Fishing Rod Top]

Comment: Never seen guides so close together.  If it were my rod (and of appropriate weight etc) I'd see if a mini glow stick  would fit in it for night fishing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was talking to the original owner, he thinks the guide hole must have spun.  I used a lighter to heat up the glue and removed it.  I will be gluing it back on later.